# Dialog layout container is too wide

Tags: android, layout, dialog

I have adapted a color picker dialog for my application.
However, when it is displayed, it is far too wide.
Either it will fill the entire width of the screen, or, if I put in a width value, it will still extend further.

Here is my layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp" >

    <my.package.settings.ColourCtrl
        android:id="@+id/colour_control"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layerType="software"
        android:tag="portrait" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Tapper sur la couleur pour l'appliquer" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etClrHexValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="HEX"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:maxLength="7"
            android:ems="7"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <my.package.settings.ColourCtrl_PanelView
            android:id="@+id/clr_OldColour"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="→" />

        <my.package.settings.ColourCtrl_PanelView
            android:id="@+id/clr_NewColour"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the UI dump of the resulting dialog :
[image]

The highlighted row is where my layout comes in.

There is no "tweaking" being done in the Dialog derived class.

Is is possible to eliminate this extra space on the right ?

**Edit :** I am working on an Android 4.2.2 (api 19) tablet, with api 16 targeted, if this helps.

Comment: I think this is because Your parent LinearLayout is 400dp wide...

Comment: Nice try, but if you look at the figures, the LinearLayout you mention is the one underneath the FrameLayout highlighted in the image and it does indeed measure 400dp (I am on a 320 dpi device, so DP values are doubled).  If I set my LinearLayout to wrap_content, the dialog will stretch across the screen.